# UITextView breaks line automatically if string is shorter than 2 lines

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I set up a `UITextView` that acts strange. If I set it's content to a long `text` it breaks it correctly at the boundaries however if the content is single lined it automatically breaks it before the last word even if it fits in one line. It created sort of a minimum of lines.

I wasn't able to find this issue posted on the web so I had to ask.

Here's the set up of the `UITextView`

```
Message * displayedMessage = [messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIFont * messageFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13];
CGSize messageSize = [displayedMessage.content sizeWithFont:messageFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(240.f, 3000.f) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
UITextView * messageTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(46.f, 0.f, messageSize.width, messageSize.height + 25)];

messageTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
messageTextView.font = messageFont;
messageTextView.editable = NO;
messageTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;
messageTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;    
messageTextView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[messageTextView setDataDetectorTypes:UIDataDetectorTypeAll];
messageTextView.text = displayedMessage.content;
[cell addSubview:messageTextView];
```

Comment: the 
     lineBreakMode:
might be your problem... try changing it to a different option

Comment: I haven't changed it so it is the default mode. Do have any guesses what mode might solve it?

Comment: no, but try experimenting the different ones.

Comment: contentInsent , try playing around with that value and see how it turns out, same thing with constrainment, all of these values could relate to your problem

Comment: apparently you can't change the line break mode of uitextviews. and i didn't find any property called constrainment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve it eventually i just had to define the textview like this, with a fixed width:

```
> UITextView * messageTextView = [[UITextView alloc]
> initWithFrame:CGRectMake(46.0f, 0.0f, 240.0f, messageSize.height +
> 25)];
```